# Cannot get the js file under the static folder in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, static

It all works in my local server, but when others try to deploy what I have done to the server, it fails.

the file system is the server something like:

```
SERVER_FOLDER
  --homepage
  ----static
  ----templates
    ------404.html
  ----app.py
  ----config.py
```

for example: The server is: `MY_SERVER`

and then in my `app.py`, I use

```
@app.route('/homepage/')
@app.route('/homepage/index')
def index():
    # TODO
```

to define the homepage, and `@app.errorhandler(404)` to redirect all the not found page to `404.html`

So I can get access to my homepage with `http://MY_SERVER/homepage/`, a little different than my local server. That's one thing that I am confused.

What I think is that the `app.py` runs under the `MY_SERVER` rather than `MY_SERVER/homepage` right?

But, in this way, when I run a template in my template file, and the `html` template file will use the `js` file under the `static` folder. the response always shows the `js` file is not found.

1. when I use `<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='file.js') }}"></script>`, it shows not found in `MY_SERVER/static` and return to 404
2. when I try `<script src="../homepage/static/file.js"></script>`, same result.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Build toward your solution:

1. Get flask serving image files from static

   Put an image in the static directory and call it from your browser:  http://yoursite/static/some_image_there.jpg

   Plug away until that works.
2. Get flask serving the js file directly to your browser

   Now put your js file into static and do as you did for the image.
   Plug away until you can call it from the browser:
   http://yoursite/static/yourfile.js
3. get your html to call the js file from static

   Now you know that there is no problem actually serving the file, and you know the exact url to it.  So it's not a big step to getting the HTML to reference it and your browser to load it.